# What is the meaning of "Vamos embora!" / "Bora?"

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, expressões

I hear this expression very often in situations, when somebody asks me whether we want to start/go/leave, so I guess it's something like "Let's go!"

But I don't really understand why "embora" is used here. I guess It's some kind of slang.

Could you enlighten me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a very standard expression, not slang at all. `Embora` is an adverb there meaning "fora daqui". You can even omit `vamos`, and say only `Embora!`, using it as an interjection, though that is more likely to mean *Vai-te/Vá-se/Vão-se/Ide-vos embora*.

Some times though, in informal use, `embora` can be used beside `vamos` without having any meaning (just as a modal particle indicating encouragement -- hortative modality). `Vamos` can also be omitted and `embora` shortened to `bora` (even more informal):

> Vamos lá embora comer!
>   Bora comer!

In the first sentence, `embora` could be omitted without much being lost, the sentence would be just a little weaker. On the other hand, `lá` adds a touch of impatience, though not as much as in *Let's eat already*.

Dictionaries also tell us that, as an adverb, it can mean "em boa hora" (the locution whence it originally came), but I don't think I've ever heard it as such. [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/embora) marks it as obsolescent, but not [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/embora). Do not confuse it qith `embora` used as a conjunction, which expresses concession.

Comment: *bora* is shorthand for *embora*, that in itself is shorthand for *em boa hora*, a really really obsolescent term.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy In Portugal, "em boa hora" sounds a bit old fashioned, but not more than that. Using "embora" to mean "em boa hora", however...